# React Touch events in Internet Explorer are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, internet-explorer, reactjs

I build and application using React,
this app works fine over IOS,Android, Chrome, Firefox,
but I found that in IE , the touch events
(onTouchCancel onTouchEnd onTouchMove onTouchStart)
 are not firing.

I tested some examples of react at react-rocks page 
like http://swizec.github.io/react-particles-experiment/
it doesn't  works over IE.

So in conclusion my question is, Does react support IE touch Events?
Is there a way to implement or subscribe the events to a component?

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: what version of ie? http://caniuse.com/#search=touch

Comment: Thanks for your response, I decided the use of react-hammerjs to avoid this kind of troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use react-hammerjs to avoid this kind of troubles in my cross-platform application.

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-hammerjs
http://hammerjs.github.io/api/